# Unable to load vue component in laravel blade file

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am new in laravel vue project, i want to load vue component in laravel blade file, but my changes are not reflected in laravel blade file. my vue file content is not loaded into blade file, example component return empty. There is no error in console network log.
please help me to solve my problem.

ExampleComponent.vue

```
    <template>
        <ul class="chat">
            <li class="left clearfix">
                <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h1>
                        Test
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                       Test 12
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import Echo from "laravel-echo";
    
        export default {
           data(){
               return{
               lists:[]
               }
           },
           mounted(){
               this.fetchList();
           },
           methods:{
               fetchList(){
                   Echo.channel('lists')
                   .listen('DataUpdate'),(e) =>{
                       console.log(e);
                   }
               }
           }
        }
    </script>
```

app.js

```
    require('./bootstrap');
    
    window.Vue = require('vue');
    import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
    Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
    
    Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
    
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
    });
```

list.blade.php

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
    
    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>
    
                    <div id="app">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <example-component></example-component>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

web.php

```
   

     Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('welcome');
        });
    
        Auth::routes();
        
        Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
        Route::get('form','HomeController@showform')->name('ShowForm');
        Route::post('saveform', 'HomeController@SaveForm')->name('saveform');
        Route::get('/listsall', 'HomeController@lists')->name('listsall');
        Route::get('/test','HomeController@test')->name('test');
```